# Joining with null

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have two tables and I want to join them with null values in it.

Sample data of my first table(A_TEST):

```
+--+----+
|ID|NAME|
+--+----+
|  |a   |
|1 |b   |
|1 |c   |
+--+----+
```

Sample data of my second table(B_TEST):

```
+--+----+
|ID|NAME|
+--+----+
|1 |d   |
|2 |e   |
|3 |f   |
+--+----+
```

I need to achieve the result by joining a_test.id = b_test.id and if there is null values in it I need to fetch them too. So I tried to write query as below,

```
select a_test.id,a_test.name,b_test.id,b_test.name
from a_test,b_test
where (a_test.id = b_test.id
or a_test.id is null);
```

I got output as below,

```
+--+----+--+----+
|ID|NAME|ID|NAME|
+--+----+--+----+
|  |a   |1 |d   |
|  |a   |2 |e   |
|  |a   |3 |f   |
|1 |b   |1 |d   |
|1 |c   |1 |d   |
+--+----+--+----+
```

But my expected result is, since id 1 is there in my a_test i need the corresponding row from b_test also.See output below

```
+--+----+--+----+
|ID|NAME|ID|NAME|
+--+----+--+----+
|  |a   |1 |d   |
|1 |b   |1 |d   |
|1 |c   |1 |d   |
+--+----+--+----+
```

I tried with outer joins also but that also does not give me the expected output.

Comment: Why do you think that `1 d` row from `b_test` corresponds to `null a` row from `a_test`?

Comment: How is the dbms supposed to understand you don't want the output you have specified you get? You need one more condition!

Comment: @defaultlocale - since id 1 is there in a_test table am expecting to get the records from b_test that is also having id as 1

Comment: Why do you join (null, a) with (1, d) and not for example with (2, e)?

Comment: "*since id 1 is there in my a_test i need the corresponding row from b_test*" and what is the corresponding "value" for `NULL` in the other table?

Comment: @arunb2w id is null in for name `a`. id is 1 for other rows.

Comment: "since id 1 is there in my a_test" - i don't get it. And what if you also had some record with id = 2 in a_test? Would you join null with 1, 2 or both of them?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - In my a_test table am having id 1 and i need to get all the rows with the same id as 1 from b_test table.Since am having id 1 in a_test table am expecting to get the matched values from b_test table and also the rows with null value

Comment: What if there are rows with id = 42 or id = 365326532 as well in that table? Which one do you choose then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the data wont have different values for the id it will be always the same value

Comment: the data will be always same for all the rows. it will not have multiple values

Answer (score 1):

Your own query is almost correct (although you shouldn't use error-prone comma-separated joins that went out of fashion some twenty years ago). You are only missing the condition what must match in case of a_test.id is null (which is: the b_test.id must be in table a_test).

```
select 
  a.id as a_id,
  a.name as a_name,
  b.id as b_id,
  b.name as b_name
from a_test a
join b_test b on 
  (a.id = b.id) 
 or
  (a.id is null and b.id in (select id from a_test));
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fae22/2.

Answer (score 0):

However strange and meaningless your requirement is, this query gives you your expected result:

```
select A.*, B.*
from a_test A
    join b_test B
        on A.id = B.id
union all
select A.*, B.*
from a_test A
    cross join b_test B
where A.id is null
    and exists (
        select 1
        from a_test Ax
        where Ax.id = B.id
    )
order by 2, 4
;
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If a a_test.id NULL is supposed to be treated as 1 when joining, use COALESCE and a sub-query to find replacing value (to be figured out by yourself, just make sure it doesn't return more than one row):

```
select a_test.id,a_test.name,b_test.id,b_test.name
from a_test,b_test
where COALESCE(a_test.id,(select integervalue from sometable)) = b_test.id
```

Comment: We cannot use constant here since the value may differ from 1 , but the value will be same for all the rows

Comment: @arunb2w, edited. What do you think about that solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a_test.id,a_test.name,b_test.id,b_test.name
from a_test,b_test
where a_test.id = b_test.id(+)
```

But, what are you want see, when a_test.id is null or missing?

Comment: Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` operator and use an explicit (modern) `LEFT JOIN` instead.